# elastic search "multi Match" query failing while search on all existing fields of index

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a scenario of using "multi_match" query to search on all the fields of a index, but while doing so i am getting an error as mentioned below.
According to my preliminary investigation i suppose the issue could be because of field of type date present in the index, and ES is unable to parse my search string to date and do a comparison.

Note :All the fields present in the index are created using dynamic template , so i couldn't know the name of the fields  and because of that i am running my query on all fields.

Any help is appreciated.

Query:

```
GET /indexname/_search
{
  "query": {
"bool" : {
"should" : [
{
"multi_match" : {
"query" : "mazda",
"fields" : [
"analyzedFields.*"
],
"type" : "best_fields",
"operator" : "OR",
"slop" : 0,
"prefix_length" : 0,
"max_expansions" : 50,
"zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
"fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
"boost" : 1.0
}
}
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"boost" : 1.0
}
}
}
```

error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]: [failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "kapturedate.service_information.ja_jp",
        "node": "mpVDNnyiRJy-bLvz3bDUuA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"should\" : [\n      {\n        \"multi_match\" : {\n          \"query\" : \"mazda\",\n          \"fields\" : [\n            \"analyzedFields.STARTDATE.actualdate^1.0\"\n          ],\n          \"type\" : \"best_fields\",\n          \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n          \"slop\" : 0,\n          \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n          \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n          \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n          \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n          \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "EqzcPvzUQcy63TIzYi_N6g",
          "index": "kapturedate.service_information.ja_jp",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]: [failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]]",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]",
              "caused_by": {
                "type": "date_time_parse_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]: [failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]]",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse date field [mazda] with format [strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-mm-dd||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/mm/dd||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss]",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "date_time_parse_exception",
          "reason": "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* don't know what fields you've got and/or you cannot retrieve this information before executing the query, I'd suggest adjusting your dynamic templates such that all fields are indexed as `text` by default and then if the system encounters a date-like field, it'll create another field property in the form of, say, `my_datelike_field.as_date`.

That way, all your fields are now searchable using `multi_match` and you can *still* perform optimized date range/histograms. The same applies to numbers, geo points, etc. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62937255/8160318) should get you started.